# php singlequote not working on sprintf properly

Tags: php, string

I use `sprintf()` on my program to output some tabs and newlines. I noticed a part of my program not working properly.

As I inspected the part that isn't working, I noticed that I used a single quote `'` instead of a doublequote `"` and the program actually outputs a `\t` instead of a inivisible tab space.

I thought the two are similar and the reason for having two delimeters for php is for us to be able to insert single or doublequote in a string or `echo` them without inserting escape characters.

Would there be a difference in assigning variables aside from the one I discovered

```
$a = "qq";
$b = 'qq';
```

Would they be stored in the computer's memory in a different manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer to the manual that specifies that single quotes in php consider most escape sequences as litterals, contrary ot double quotes:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: `variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.`  Found it. Thanks dude, now I know why. They simply don't get expanded.

Answer (score 1):

- single quote is faster than double
- double quote can parse php variable. i.e. **$a=2;** and if you use **echo "a is: $a";** then it will print **a is: 2** but single quote will print **a is: $a**

Comment: So by changing most of my doublequotes in my php codes will somehow make it execute a tiny biy faster.  Also I wasn't aware of the php variable trick you showed as your example. Nice one.

Comment: Yes. It is slightly faster to use single quotes.
This is because when you use double quotes PHP has to parse to check if there are variables in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you use single quotes for the format string (like you should do, since there 
aren't any variable conversions to do as long as you don't need any special chars), 
the given examples won't work because of the backslash before the $ (needs to be 
escaped in double quoted strings - but not in single quoted!) http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php
```